# How can I change Modelica MultiBody component parameters by working on the XML file?

Tags: java, xml, modelica, openmodelica

I have created a trivial model of a pendulum in Modelica. After that, I have built the model so that the .xml file and the .exe file were generated.

```
 model TestJAVA_v2
 inner Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.World world annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-86, 28}, extent = {{-10, 
-10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
 Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Joints.Revolute revolute1(n = {1, 0, 0}, 
 phi(fixed = true, start = 0.785398))  annotation(
 Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-46, 28}, extent = 
 {{-10, 
-10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
 Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Parts.PointMass pointMass1 annotation(
 Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {16, 28}, extent = {{-10, 
-10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
 Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Parts.BodyShape bodyShape1(r = {0, 1, 1}, r_CM 
 = bodyShape1.r / 2)  annotation(
 Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-14, 26}, extent = 
 {{-10, 
-10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
equation
connect(bodyShape1.frame_b, pointMass1.frame_a) annotation(
Line(points = {{-4, 26}, {16, 26}, {16, 28}, {16, 28}}, color = {95, 95, 
95}));
connect(revolute1.frame_b, bodyShape1.frame_a) annotation(
Line(points = {{-36, 28}, {-24, 28}, {-24, 26}, {-24, 26}}, color = {95, 95, 
95}));
connect(world.frame_b, revolute1.frame_a) annotation(
Line(points = {{-76, 28}, {-58, 28}, {-58, 28}, {-56, 28}}, color = {95, 95, 
95}));
annotation(
uses(Modelica(version = "3.2.2")),
experiment(StartTime = 0, StopTime = 15, Tolerance = 0.001, Interval = 
0.0010002),
__OpenModelica_simulationFlags(iim = "none", lv = "LOG_STATS", s = 
 "dassl"));
end TestJAVA_v2;
```

Using an xml parser I am able to change the mass of the BodyShape and the vector r (Vector from frame_a to frame_b resolved in frame_a). But after simulating, I found out that only the mass has changed, while the length of the component did not. Is it possible to modify this vector through the xml file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some parameters cannot be changed without recompiling the model.

Search in the `ScalarVariable` for `isValueChangeable` attribute.
If `isValueChangeable = "false"` then you cannot change that value via the xml file.

This can happen because:

1. the parameter is structural (array dimensions depend on it)
2. the parameter has `annotation(Evaluate=true)` which basically makes it a constant

More information on edit, after some more analysis:

- the current front-end forces evaluation of the `bodyShape1.r` so it makes it a constant that cannot be changed
- you can use the nightly builds (v1.13) and run `omc -d=newInst` or set in OMEdit the OMC flags to `-d=newInst` to use the new front-end implementation that allows `bodyShape1.r` to be changeable.

With `-d=newInst` you get:

```
  <ScalarVariable
    name = "bodyShape1.r[1]"
    valueReference = "1711"
    description = "Vector from frame_a to frame_b resolved in frame_a"
    variability = "parameter" isDiscrete = "true"
    causality = "internal" isValueChangeable = "true"
    alias = "noAlias"
    classIndex = "86" classType = "rPar"
    isProtected = "false" hideResult = "false"
    fileName = "c:/home/adrpo33/dev/OpenModelica/build/lib/omlibrary/Modelica 3.2.2/Mechanics/MultiBody/Parts.mo" startLine = "1038" startColumn = "5" endLine = "1039" endColumn = "59" fileWritable = "true">
    <Real start="0.0" fixed="true" useNominal="false" unit="m" />
  </ScalarVariable>
```

which has `isValueChangeable = "true"`.

```
adrpo33@computer MINGW64 /c/home/adrpo33/dev/OMTesting/mb
$ ./TestJAVA_v2.exe -override=bodyShape1.r[1]=2 -lv=LOG_ALL | grep 'bodyShape1.r\['
LOG_SOLVER        | info    | read override values: bodyShape1.r[1]=2
LOG_SOLVER        | info    | override bodyShape1.r[1] = 2
|                 | |       | | Real bodyShape1.r[1](start=2, fixed=true, {nominal=1}, min=-1.79769e+308, max=1.79769e+308)
|                 | |       | | Real bodyShape1.r[2](start=1, fixed=true, {nominal=1}, min=-1.79769e+308, max=1.79769e+308)
|                 | |       | | Real bodyShape1.r[3](start=1, fixed=true, {nominal=1}, min=-1.79769e+308, max=1.79769e+308)
|                 | |       | | | [87] parameter Real bodyShape1.r[1](start=2, fixed=true) = 2
|                 | |       | | | [88] parameter Real bodyShape1.r[2](start=1, fixed=true) = 1
|                 | |       | | | [89] parameter Real bodyShape1.r[3](start=1, fixed=true) = 1
```

Seems to be working fine with `omc -d=newInst` and `Model -override`

Comment: You might be able to force to not evaluate the parameter but you would need to change the code for all the classes that define this parameter and remove annotation(Evaluate=true) if it has it. If the parameter is structural then is not possible to change it without recompiling the model, no matter what you do.

Comment: I would like to thank you for the answer. 
The objective was to change this parameter iteratively in an optimization algorithm. However, I think they are structural for the model so that it is not possible to work on them through the xml file. 
Thank you again for your time.

Comment: Try with -d=newInst, it should work fine (I hope). You also don't need to use the xml file to change these, you can use command line on the model executable via: Model -override=r[1]=1,r[2]=2,r[3]=3.

Comment: I have downloaded the nightly builds (v1.13) here:
https://build.openmodelica.org/omc/builds/windows/nightly-builds/64bit/
I have added the simulation flag in OMEdit but the attribute isValueChangeable is still false for bodyShape1.r. Maybe I installed the wrong exe?
I need to work with the XML file because I have implemented some java classes which work with this kind of file. 
I would like to thank you again for your answer.
Best regards

Comment: From OMEdit: Tools->Options->Simulation->OMC Flags

Comment: Now it works fine with this trivial Model. I have tried to use the same debug flag on my model but it does not work. Sometimes it says that some frame is not connected (which does not make sense because the model is built correctly without -d=newInst). Other times the following error is shown: 

[8] 15:11:22 Translation Error
[C:/dev/OM64bit/OMCompiler/Compiler/SimCode/SimCodeMain.mo: 449:7-449:78]: Internal error C:\OpenModelica1.13.0-dev-64bit\bin\OMEdit.exe: [unknown function name] failed

Do you have any suggestions?
Thank you again. Best regards

Comment: Unfortunately it seems the new front-end might have issues with your model as is not finished yet. We are working on fixing all the issues but it will take some time.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking that too. I really appreciated your help.Thank you. 
Best regards.